# Assymetric filter size on range images in CNN?

Tags: conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I was wondering if there has been any know-how about the filter sizes in CNNs when using panorama images? Would it make sense to stretch the filters the same way as to the ratio of the height and the width of the image?